# LEGO cleaning dust?

Tags: cleaning, tools

I'm a LEGO seller and buy around 20-50kg of LEGO bricks a week. 
I need to clean these items before I sell them.

Currently I'm using the standard method using a bucket and soapy water.
However, this is not working on plates etc. Mainly the dust is still on the parts.

I have searched for the materials LEGO uses which is mainly ABS. This material has not such good wetting properties. Now I could imagine the studs on the plates could prevent wetting and thus cleaning of the parts? Is it possible to lower the surface tension of the water?

Furthermore does anyone have good tips on how to prevent this in the future ?

I have found thing but its all about keeping your LEGO collection clean from dust. and I do not want to put the parts in the washing machine.

Comment: Have you tried using a soft bristle toothbrush to clean the plates when you have them in soapy water?

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment, yes i tried but often the surface of the plates will be scratched when the dust/dirt came off :(